# Displaying specific information on aspx page using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am building a website with ASP.NET Web Forms, and a SQL database.

On one particular page I have a number of houses with some informations.
There are 571 houses in total.
When I click on a particular house, I want to bring up a new page with more information about that house.
All the data is coming from a table in the database.

Is there a way of knowing which house has been selected, and display the data on the new aspx page for that house?

I know I could create many separate aspx pages for each house but there are 571 houses and there would have to be 571 aspx pages. That is far too much wasted code.
When I click on the house name I want only one aspx page but I want it to know that I have selected that house and display the information for that specific one. Like its accessing the database information for that house and displays it.

The main obstacle here is knowing what house has been selected. I know how to display information from a database.

**Houses.aspx**

[image]

When I click a house name I want to display a page like the one below.

**HouseInfo.aspx**

[image]

**HouseInfo.aspx.cs**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built, Description, Families FROM Houses ORDER BY Name DESC", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            lblId.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                            lblName.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                            lblTown.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                            lblNear.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                            lblStatus.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                            lblBuilt.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                            lblDesc.Text = reader[6].ToString();
                            lblFam.Text = reader[7].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

This is how I am accessing the database to display some of the info on the HouseInfo page already.

**HouseInfo.aspx**

```
<b>ID:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Name of House:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Townland:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblTown" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Near:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblNear" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Status/Public Access:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server </asp:Label>
<br /><b>Date Built:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblBuilt" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Description:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br /><b>Associated Families:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblFam" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Houses.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Houses" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Houses.aspx.cs" Inherits="Houses_of_Mayo.images.Houses" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <script>
        $(function () { setCurrentTab('tab2'); });
    </script>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            <div class="body">
                <h1>Houses</h1>

                <ul id="rooms">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <a href="HouseInfo.aspx">
                                    <img src="x" alt="img" /></a>
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="HouseInfo.aspx"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></a></h2>
                                <p>
                                    <b>ID: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Name of House: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Townland: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Townland") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Near: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Near") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Status/Public Access: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br />

                                    <b>Date Built: </b>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Built") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
            style="padding:8px; margin:2px; background:#ac9e94; border:solid 1px #666; font:8pt; color:#594334; display: inline-block;"
            CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "page_enabled" : "page_disabled" %>'
            OnClick="Page_Changed" OnClientClick='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "return false;" : "" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Houses.aspx.cs**

```
private int PageSize = 5;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.GetCustomersPageWise(1);
            }
        }

        private void GetCustomersPageWise(int pageIndex)
        {
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetHousesPageWise", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                    cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    con.Open();
                    IDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    rptData.DataSource = idr;
                    rptData.DataBind();
                    idr.Close();
                    con.Close();
                    int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value);
                    this.PopulatePager(recordCount, pageIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        private void PopulatePager(int recordCount, int currentPage) 
        {
            double dblPageCount = (double)((decimal)recordCount / Convert.ToDecimal(PageSize));
            int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(dblPageCount);
            List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
            if (pageCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage));
                }
            }
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Page_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
            this.GetCustomersPageWise(pageIndex);
        }
```

**Map (HouseInfo.aspx)**

[image]

**HouseInfo.aspx**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.613873, -9.668301);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                                  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                                  '</div>' +
                                  '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Aasleagh Lodge</h2>' +
                                  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                                  '<b>ID:</b> A1' +
                                  '</br><b>Name:</b> Aasleagh Lodge' +
                                  '</br><b>Townland:</b> Srahatloe' +
                                  '</br><b>Ref:</b> 1' +
                                  '</br><b>Latitude:</b> 53.613873' +
                                  '</br><b>Longitude:</b> -9.668301' +
                                  '</div>' +
                                  '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            var image = 'Images/icon56.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Aasleagh Lodge',
                icon: image
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**HouseInfo Table**

```
[Id]       CHAR (10)      NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Townland] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Ref]      INT            NULL,
    [Lat]      FLOAT (53)     NULL,
    [Lng]      FLOAT (53)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_HouseInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

Comment: lblId has the id for the house you are viewing no?

Comment: show us your Houses.aspx.cs, so I can add that part to answer too

Comment: Hi! I have edited your question so it's a bit more clear what you need.

Comment: I need your Houses.aspx.cs, your question clear enough, no need explaination. just paste your Houses.aspx.cs and Houses.aspx codes in your question, like you did for HouseInfo

Comment: posted Houses.aspx and Houses.aspx.cs

Comment: @Mert I also want to display the house location and map details like the way I displayed the other info on the page. This info is coming from a different table in the database. How would I go about doing this? I have updated the question with the code needed.

Comment: I am asuming HouseInfo tables Id and house tables Id are same, "SELECT h.Id, h.Name, h.Townland, h.Near, h.Status, h.Built, h.Description, h.Families, hi.Townland, hi.Lat, hi.Lng FROM Houses h, HouseInfo hi WHERE hi.Id = h.Id ORDER BY h.Name DESC"

Comment: I had this done already. I mean I am not sure how to display the info from the database using the content string and the coordinates on the map of each house "var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.613873, -9.668301);"

Comment: palce these above the page_load; public object Lat { get; set; }
public object Lng { get; set; } set their values in pageload and use like ; new google.maps.LatLng(<%=Lat%>,<%=Lng%>);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79752/discussion-between-prodiablo-and-mert).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this code you are sending Id of house to other page.

```
<a href='<%# "HouseInfo.aspx?HouseId=" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'>
                    <img src="x" alt="img" /></a>
```

and here you are getting that Id back

```
string HouseId = Request.Params["HouseId"].ToString();
```

also in here you are filtering your data to only get that houses information

```
"SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built, Description, Families FROM Houses WHERE Id = '" + HouseId + "' ORDER BY Name DESC"
```

**complete code ;**

HouseInfo.aspx.cs

```
string HouseId = Request.Params["HouseId"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built, Description, Families FROM Houses WHERE Id = '" + HouseId + "' ORDER BY Name DESC", connection))
    {
         connection.Open();
         using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  lblId.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                  lblName.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                  lblTown.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                  lblNear.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                  lblStatus.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                  lblBuilt.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                  lblDesc.Text = reader[6].ToString();
                  lblFam.Text = reader[7].ToString();
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Houses.aspx

```
<ul id="rooms">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href='<%# "HouseInfo.aspx?HouseId=" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'>
                <img src="x" alt="img" /></a>
                <h2>
                <a href='<%# "HouseInfo.aspx?HouseId=" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></a></h2>
                 <p>
                 <b>ID: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <br />
                 <b>Name of House: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <br />
                 <b>Townland: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Townland") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <br />
                 <b>Near: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Near") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <br />
                 <b>Status/Public Access: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <br />

                 <b>Date Built: </b>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Built") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </p>
             </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question (he doesn't know how to pass the parameters to the other page), and is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @cosmo0 If you care to read comments I am waiting his Houses.aspx.cs codes to complete that part.

Comment: posted Houses.aspx and Houses.aspx.cs

Comment: int HouseId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["HouseId"]); Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. NOTE: The ID is a char because it contains both letters and numbers

Comment: using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) Additional information: Invalid column name 'A1'. 'A1' is the ID

Comment: place quotes as I did in answer. WHERE Id = '" + HouseId + "' ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. Best (IMO) and easiest is to use query string to pass the ID (or primary key data) of the selected house to the next web-form and display data using that value.